# jquery + how to target elements after the initial DOM load

Tags: jquery

Say a form is submitted for 'validation' process (to a separate script), and returns different 'response' elements (divs to be specific) based on the input value.

How can i check a certain criteria to an element that only appears AFTER the initial DOM has been loaded? (after a click event)

```
if ($('.response:visible')) {
//do this.
}
```

****update clarifications***

The element(s) i'm trying to target, are only displayed *after* the user tries to submit a form. (eg. please check email for confirmation.)

Another way to put this..

Regardless of which event occurs, at any time **#foo** is visible, briefly keep on screen *(5sec.)*, and then fade back out. (display:none;)"

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Does that code not work? It seems like it should.

Comment: "after a click event" is different than DOM `load`. Please clearify.

Comment: A 'click event' on *what* element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean process function after loading DOM?

```
$(function(){ .... });
```

or to check item attributes?

```
if($('.response').attr('visibility')=='visible')
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the document load callback, you will need to run this code for the relevant event. In your case that may be `onsuccess` of an ajax post (not sure how you are submitting the form), or perhaps in the `onsubmit` callback.

```
if ($('.response').is(':visible')) { // --> true if any .response is visible
//do this.
}
```